# (There is no extension able to load the configuration for "sonata_block"

Tags: git, symfony

i am finding this error while generating admin panel in symfony 2.5.
can one please tell me what is this ? as i am new to symfony and unable to get it.
Error using GIT, when clear cache using, app/console cache:clear or any thing else, same error is in browser.

```
  [Symfony\Component\Config\Exception\FileLoaderLoadException]
  Cannot import resource "D:\xampp\htdocs\myassignment\app/config\config.yml"
   from "D:\xampp\htdocs\myassignment\app/config/config_dev.yml". (There is n
  o extension able to load the configuration for "sonata_block" (in D:\xampp\
  htdocs\myassignment\app/config\config.yml). Looked for namespace "sonata_bl
  ock", found "framework", "security", "twig", "monolog", "swiftmailer", "ass
  etic", "doctrine", "sensio_framework_extra", "member", "sonata_admin", "son
  ata_doctrine_orm_admin", "acme_demo", "web_profiler", "sensio_distribution"
  )


  [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException]
  There is no extension able to load the configuration for "sonata_block" (in
   D:\xampp\htdocs\myassignment\app/config\config.yml). Looked for namespace
  "sonata_block", found "framework", "security", "twig", "monolog", "swiftmai
  ler", "assetic", "doctrine", "sensio_framework_extra", "member", "sonata_ad
  min", "sonata_doctrine_orm_admin", "acme_demo", "web_profiler", "sensio_dis
  tribution"
```

Here is my code

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: @memberBundle/Resources/config/admin.yml }

framework:
    #esi:             ~
    #translator:      { fallback: "%locale%" }
    secret:          "%secret%"
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
        #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_hosts:   ~
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:
        # handler_id set to null will use default session handler from php.ini
        handler_id:  ~
    fragments:       ~
    http_method_override: true

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"

# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ ]
    #java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        #closure:
        #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/compiler.jar"
        #yui_css:
        #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar"

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   "%database_driver%"
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver, add the path in parameters.yml
        # e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
        # path:     "%database_path%"

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        auto_mapping: true

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    spool:     { type: memory }

sonata_block:
    default_contexts: [cms]
    blocks:
        # Enable the SonataAdminBundle block
        sonata.admin.block.admin_list:
            contexts:   [admin]
        # Your other blocks
```

here is my kernel

Comment: Have you added it to your `composer.json` and updated?

Comment: looks like you did not register the bundle in you AppKernel

Comment: This is almost always the case of what @johnSmith suggested...

Comment: well i did that... John

Answer (score 0):

You should register SonataBlockBundle in AppKernel.php

Answer (score 0):

The official documentation indicates the list of bundles to initialise on AppKernel.php

> ```
>         // The admin requires some twig functions defined in the security
>         // bundle, like is_granted. Register this bundle if it wasn't the case
>         // already.
>         new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
>
>         // These are the other bundles the SonataAdminBundle relies on
>         new Sonata\CoreBundle\SonataCoreBundle(),
>         new Sonata\BlockBundle\SonataBlockBundle(),
>         new Knp\Bundle\MenuBundle\KnpMenuBundle(),
>
>         // And finally, the storage and SonataAdminBundle
>         new Sonata\DoctrineORMAdminBundle\SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle(),
>         new Sonata\AdminBundle\SonataAdminBundle(),
> ```

So you forgot to initialize the SonataBlockBundle.
Don't forget to install and initialize the correct ORM/ODM for your type of driver.

More info here: https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/3-x/doc/getting_started/installation.html

Comment: I'm going through the documentation for this (test project, don't ask) - https://docs.sonata-project.org/projects/SonataAdminBundle/en/3.x/getting_started/installation/ - and it says to add SonataBlockBundle to config/bundles.php (I then added that file to config.yml as a resource)... so I guess Sonata's wrong and I have to do it the Symfony 3.4 way :/ Weird